# Travel to Bali in mid November

Tags: safety, bali, natural-disasters

I'm planning to Travel to Bali 16th of November this year, but since they have had Tsunami recently, i was wondering if it will be safe to travel there ? and are they any safety recommendation about the hotels choices or something ? 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

The recent tsunami was in Sulawesi, not Bali, which is a different island several hours' flight away and was not impacted at all.

All of Indonesia has a lot of earthquake activity, so new tsunamis are always possible.  However, Bali is a large island, if you're worried about tsunamis you can always stay in inland resort towns like Ubud.